# PhantomJS and windows azure

Tags: azure, phantomjs

Are there any instructions on how to install Phantomjs on a basic windows azure account? I need to listen on a (local) port which access requests from the main application and will respond with the FULL html.

My app uses IIS. Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. How do you even start the phantomjs process and listen on a port? Is this even possible in azure?

Comment: Didn't you find something useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[phantomjs]+azure)?

Comment: Yes I have looked at all of these and seemed either out of date or different to what I am doing

Answer (score 1):

To run phantomjs probably on windows azure you have to choose between

1. VM
2. Cloud Service

this guide it how to deploy nodejs as cloud service, you can replace nodejs with phantomjs
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-app/

You can't run phantomjs in azure website because GDI is supported yet in Azure website. but if GDI is supported just you can listen to env Port

```
var system = require('system');
var env = system.env;
console.log(env.port);
```